# Bash If statement in Case statement to output boolean value not working

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following Bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

input=true

input="$($(IFS=, read -r s ; echo "${s}bool") <<< "$input")"

IFS=,; set -f; set -- $input; out=
for i in "$@"; do
  case "$i" in
    "")
      echo "empty input not allowed"
      exit 0
      ;;
    *bool)
      if [[ "${s}" == "true" || "${s}" == "false" ]]; then
        out="$out,${i/%bool/}"
      else
        echo "value not allowed" && exit 0
      fi
      ;;
  esac
done
echo "${out:1}"
```

The input is from a TUI interface and the output will be used in an SQL insert statement as a boolean value. This is a simplified version of a larger script, hence the for loop and case statement. If I run the script I get no output at all and no error message.

What I am trying to achieve is that I get either *true* or *false* as output depending on whether $input is *true* or *false*. Please ignore `"")` in the case statement.

Can someone please help?

Comment: `read s` is run in a subshell, so `s` has no value in the main part of the script (i.e. in the `if` near the end). Also, there's no `;` or line ending before the `else`, so that'll be treated as part of the `out=...` command, rather than a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

#### If I run the script I get no output at all and no error message.

You should (unless you are a `bash` expert) take advantage of [ShellCheck – shell script analysis tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/) when you are having problems with your scripts.

Running your script through ShellCheck returns the following errors:

```
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 5:
input="$((IFS=, read -r s ; echo "${s}bool" )<<<"$input")"
       ^-- SC1102: Shells disambiguate $(( differently or not at all. For $(command substition), add space after $( . For $((arithmetics)), fix parsing errors.
                        ^-- SC2030: Modification of s is local (to subshell caused by (..) group).
 
Line 7:
IFS=,; set -f; set -- $input; out=
                      ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
IFS=,; set -f; set -- "$input"; out=
 
Line 12:
                *bool) if [[ "${s}" == "true" ||  "${s}" == "false" ]] ; then out="$out,${i/%bool/}"  else echo "value not allowed" && exit 0 ; fi;;
                              ^-- SC2031: s was modified in a subshell. That change might be lost.
                                                   ^-- SC2031: s was modified in a subshell. That change might be lost.

$
```

Fix the errors and then check the script again.

Rinse and recycle until your script is working.